# How do you give a reference to a Vec the lifetime of the struct it belongs to?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have some struct's that live for the lifetime of the application, they contain lists of variable length. This works great:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct British<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    items: &'a [&'a str],
}

static ITEMS:&[British] = &[British{name:"a", items:&["b"]}];
```

I have a `build.rs` that attempts to parse a text file to generate this list, however I am having trouble telling the Vec inside the struct to have the lifetime of the struct.  How do instantiate a struct that contains a reference to a Vec that has the same lifetime? Here is my attempt at a minimal example:

```
pub fn new_item<'a>() -> British<'a> {
    //let mut k:Vec<&'a str> = Vec::new();  
    let mut k:Vec<&'a str> = Vec::<'a>::new();

    k.push("a");
    k.push("b");

    let b = British{
        name: "fish",
        items: &k,
    };
    
    b
}

fn main() {
    let b = new_item();
    println!("Hello, world! {:?}", b);
}
```

Link to [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d4cb66ece8eed87f9eb016a31f4dcfc7).

Comment: You can't possibly return a reference to `k` a **local** of the function `new_item`. I.e. the problem isn't the lifetime of the items stored in the `Vec` but that it itself goes out of scope at the end of the function. If you change `&[]` to `Vec<>` in the definition and don't take a reference you don't even have to specify the lifetime, the compiler can work it out.

Comment: Why can't your `build.rs` generate a static item instead?

Comment: @cafce25 Vec<> is not permitted in static/const unless you lazy load.  And yes, I am creating the `build.rs`, that's literally what I am doing.

Comment: Wait `new_item` is part of your `build.rs`? Then it's possible you want to just [`Vec::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.leak) it.

Comment: @cafce25 wow, that'll do it! I didn't know such a function call existed or could exist. Thankyou.   Interestingly, the rust documentation for vec::leak provides the exact example/sample code that is needed for this situation.

Comment: I still don't understand how this entire thing works. Is everything you posted here part of the `build.rs`? Why do you need references? Why can't you have ownership? How does the `build.rs` relate to the actual code of the crate? How does the `build.rs` interact with the application? My understanding is the the `build.rs` preprocesses things and generates `.rs` files that can then be compiled, or compiles things itself. I don't see anything being generated here. Am I missing a usecase of `build.rs` I'm not aware of yet? You can't just use items from the `build.rs` it in the application...

Comment: Also, everything in here, from the question title to the content screams [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me ...

Comment: @Finomnis Its fundamentally a question about how lifetime management works for structs. I am trying to work out how to control the lifetime of an array. In every language I have used so far, it is possible to create a struct that can be initialized as a static (global) variable with variable length arrays, but in Rust, it is not clear how to do this, (If it is even possible)

Comment: @Jay Opposed to other languages, Rust has a policy of "nothing runs before the main function". That means all global statics need to be created at compile time, meaning their constructor must be `const` compatible. But I'm not sure if that relates to your problem, as I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So yes, your first attempt was correct, and you stated that this is what you need. So why don't you generate exactly that using the `build.rs`? Again, you don't generate **objects** in your `build.rs`, you generating **Rust code**. You can generate exactly the code in your first snippet, derived from input data known at compile time. Examples can be seen here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-script-examples.html